# how can I use xsl to ignore duplicates

Tags: xslt

Ok, I know this has been covered a couple of times, but previous answers don't seem to give the result I'm looking for.  It could be that xslt is not processing as linearly as I expect it to, but I don't know how to address it if it's not.

Let's say I have an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <section>A</section>
  <divider/>
  <divider/>
  <section>B</section>
  <divider/>
  <section>C</section>
  <divider/>
  <divider/>
  <section>D</section>
  <divider/>
</root>
```

As you can see, there are occasionally duplicate elements. With an xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="divider">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::divider)">
      <xsl:text>--</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was expecting to see

```
A
--
B
--
C
--
D
--
```

... but that's not what's happening.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

What I'm getting right now is:

```
A
--
B
C
D
```

Comment: Do you mind adding what is actually happening so we can see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preceding-sibling::divider` selects any preceding sibling `divider` element. If you want to check that the immediate preceding sibling is not a `divider` then use `not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::divider])`.

Comment: Ok, yes, this fixes it.  Could you elaborate a bit more on why it works? You're saying that on the `preceding-sibling` axis, grab all elements, then select the first, then... ?

Comment: Yes, `preceding-sibling::*` selects all preceding sibling element, `preceding-sibling::*[1]` selects the immediately preceding sibling element (as that axis is a reverse axis (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) and the predicate `[self::divider]` then checks the element is a `divider` element.