# use xlst to count intermediary elements

Tags: xslt

How can I count intermediary elements?  I think the solution to this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137921/how-can-i-use-xsl-to-ignore-duplicates). Supposing I had something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <cell>Title</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell padding='true'>Chapter</cell>
    <cell>example additional cell</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell padding='true'>Chapter</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell padding='true'>Chapter</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>Title</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell padding='true'>Chapter</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>Title</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell padding='true'>Chapter</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell padding='true'>Chapter</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>Title</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell padding='true'>Chapter</cell>
  </row>
</root>
```

And, applying a transformation like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/root">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!--these are the indented ones-->
        <xsl:when test="cell/@padding">
        <xsl:number
                value="count(preceding-sibling::row[child::cell[1][@padding]]) + 1"
                format="a.&#x20;"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:number
                value="count(preceding-sibling::row[child::cell[1][not(@padding)]]) + 1"
                format="1.&#x20;"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="cell/text()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting this result:

```
1. Title
  a. Chapter
  b. Chapter
  c. Chapter
2. Title
  d. Chapter
3. Title
  e. Chapter
  f. Chapter
4. Title
  g. Chapter
```

What I would like is to have the "sub" items restart their numbering.  I just can't figure how change the axis to stop looking back at earlier elements.

I was looking to have the "chapters" counted.  So:

```
1. Title
  a. Chapter
  b. Chapter
  c. Chapter
2. Title
  a. Chapter
3. Title
  a. Chapter
  b. Chapter
4. Title
  a. Chapter
```

Comment: Please post the output you want and explain what a "sub" item is in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row[not(cell/@padding)] | row/cell[@padding]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:number count="row[not(cell/@padding)]" format="1. "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="cell"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cell">
    <xsl:number count="cell[@padding]" level="any" from="row[not(cell/@padding)]" format="   a. "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ok, yeah, that pointed me in the right direction.  I can't change the template matching, but I can use the `count` and `from` to identify the origin and what should be counted.